# Equality inference in F# + records with mutable fields

Tags: f#, comparison, equality, mutable, inference

The common equality/comparison members design guideline is to not implement structural equality on mutable reference types, but take a look at F# record types with mutable fields:

```
type Value = { mutable value: int }

let mutableRecord = { value = 1 }
let xs = Map.ofList [ mutableRecord, "abc"
                      { value = 2 }, "def" ]

let abc = Map.find { value=1 } xs
mutableRecord.value <- 3
let abc = Map.find { value=3 } xs // KeyNotFoundException!
```

The `Map` is sorted internally, but `mutable` record fields allows me to change ordering while record instance is already inside map and this is very bad.

I think F# should infer `[<NoEquality>]` and `[<NoComparison>]` modes for F# record types that declares mutable fields, isn't it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not an unreasonable stance.

There might be some clever ways to leverage this feature usefully, though I haven't thought about it deeply enough.  This is basically the same thing as when you put a mutable type in a `Dictionary`, and you get what you deserve.  (Languages can't prevent every misuse, which is why we have design guidelines and programmer judgment to fill in the gaps :) )

Anyway, there's no changing it now.